# bootstrap slide + fancy box solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am inquiring on if here is a "drop in" solution for an image slider with touch controls and a possible fancy box(click on enlarge) built in? (The plan is to host the images and allow the client to keep adding images to their Google Drive account, without needing me to create the "modal / fancybox" code for every picture they add.

I have tried https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4 It worked great as a slider but on mobile the pictures are the wrong sizes, needing a page refresh. The touch controls don't work that well either.

Hoping for some input, I am using bootstrap but any responsive solution will do.

Comment: Might try http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html for a slider, but a fancy box is still needed...one where I only need to declare once and not per picture.

Comment: What does not work with bootstrap's carousel and modal?

Comment: We would like to have 5 images per slide, and like I stated above I would like to have one fancybox that every picture will call, instead of a modal for every picture.

Comment: You could use a modal and just change the image source when opening it?

Comment: Go had and post that as an answer so I can mark it off, thank you.

Comment: Sure, I will write up an example for you shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use bootstraps [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) as a picture slider, then use a modal to popup a larger image and just change the [image's](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) source so you only have to make one [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <!-- Change image source for large popup-->
        <img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```